# Parse script files in a folder and tokenize multiline string in Powershell + RegEx

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0, tokenize, multiline

Another `PowerShell` + `RegEx` dilemma. 
Trying to parse a folder/directory containing script files. Locate the scripts that contain setup of variables, and output the script file name as well as the values, assigned to the variables.

The rules as I see them are:

- The needed step will always begin with `MVL` which may or may not be
  preceded by 1 or more spaces.
- The step ends on a colon (`;`).
- The assigned value ends on `',`
- Need to display variable values for all `MVL` steps in the script.

What I need to capture is the name of the script file, and the values for variables `SRCFILE`, `SERVER`, `TARGETFILE`.

The data I am looking for would be something like this:

> ```
> MVL       SRCFILE='\PATH\FOLDER\FILENAME.TXT   ',SERVER='SERVERNAME             ',
>       TARGETFILE='TARGET.TXT   ',PARM1=O,PARM2=N,PARM3=N,PARM4=Y,PARM5=N,PARM6=' ',
>       PARM7=N,PARM8='NONE  ',PARM8='                              ',
>       PARM9=00;
> Other lines I don't care about
>
> Could be blank lines
> * Comment lines will begin with asterisk, need to skip
> MVL       SRCFILE='\PATH\FOLDER2\FILENAME'&1'.TXT   ',
>           SERVER='SERVERNAME2             ',
>       TARGETFILE='TARGET2.TXT   ',PARM1=O,PARM2=N,PARM3=N,PARM4=Y,PARM5=N,PARM6=' ',
>       PARM7=N,PARM8='NONE  ',PARM8='                              ',
>       PARM9=00;
> ```

I started with the RegEx pattern, but am at a total loss now. I know that this reads the data only from the specified file.

The latest I have is this, but I can't get it to look in the consecutive lines and to capture the needed values:

```
Select-String -Pattern "(?:^[\s]*?MVL\s*?SRCFILE=')(.*)(?:\s+?',)(?:.*$)" c:\scripts\Script1.scl
```

So, if the sample data was located in `Script1.scl` my output would look like:

```
   Script1.scl    \PATH\FOLDER\FILENAME.TXT       SERVERNAME    TARGET.TXT
   Script1.scl    \PATH\FOLDER\FILENAME'&1'.TXT   SERVERNAME2   TARGET2.TXT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final script:

```
## Folders to check
$TargetFolder1 = “C:\scripts”
$path = $TargetFolder1 + "\*.scl"

$regex = "(?:^[\s]*?MVL\s*?SRCFILE=')"

$scriptFiles=Select-String -Path $path -Pattern $regex | ForEach-Object {$_}

$varObjs = @()

foreach($file in $scriptFiles)
{
    $currentFile = [io.file]::readalltext($file.Path) #-replace "[\r\n]", " "
    $regex = "(?smi)(?:^[\s]*?MVL\s*?SRCFILE=')([^']+)\s*?'\s*?,\r?\n?(?:\s*?SERVER='([^']+)\s*?'\s*?,\r?\n?)?(?:\s*?TARGETFILE='([^']+)\s*?'\s*?,)?"  

    $b = select-string -InputObject $currentFile -AllMatches -Pattern $regex 


    for($i = 0; $i -le $b.Matches.Count-1; $i++)
    {
         $varObj = New-Object System.Object
         $varObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ScriptName -Value $file.Path 
         $varObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SrcFile -Value $b.Matches[$i].Groups[1].value 
         $varObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Server -Value $b.Matches[$i].Groups[2].value
         $varObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TargetFile -Value $b.Matches[$i].Groups[3].value

        $varObjs += $varObj
    }

}

$varObjs | Export-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -path c:\Test\Results.txt

exit
```

Comment: Good job. Some notes about site usage: You should post the solution in your answer, not the question body. It is also courteous to upvote any answers that assisted you in finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can have select-string search multiple files in two ways:

```
Select-String -Pattern "..." c:\scripts\*.sc1
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem c:\scripts\*.sc1 -recurse | Select-String -Pattern "..."
```

Now it is search multiple files where it find matches it will output a MatchInfo object with the follow properties:

```
   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method     type GetType()
RelativePath Method     string RelativePath(string directory)
ToString     Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string directory)
Context      Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext Context {get;set;}
Filename     Property   string Filename {get;}
IgnoreCase   Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}
Line         Property   string Line {get;set;}
LineNumber   Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}
Matches      Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}
Path         Property   string Path {get;set;}
Pattern      Property   string Pattern {get;set;}
```

You can extract the filename and regex capture groups like so:

```
Select-String -Pattern "..." c:\scripts\*.sc1 | Select Filename,
    @{n='ServerName';e={$_.matches.groups[1].Value}}
```

Comment: Keith, thank you for your response. Please let me clarify, my problem seems to be that I can't get to capture the string up until `;` which can be few lines further. My current expression only returns one line.

Comment: Keith, I am asking for assistance with setting up my RegEx pattern.  Thus far, I am only capturing the MVL line only. I can't figure out who to specify to look further until it sees `;`.

Comment: Try modifying the regex to `"(?:^[\s]*?MVL\s*?SRCFILE=')([^']+)'\s*,\s*SERVER='([^']+)"` in order to create two capture groups to get SRCFILE and SERVER.

Comment: Are the lines shown in your example like that in the file i.e. on separate lines?  If that is the case then you will run into problems with this approach because it matches line by line and you need to match across lines.  If that is the case, use something like [io.file]::readalltext('C:\Scripts\script.sc1') to read the file as a single string.  Then modify your regex like so `"(?smi)(?:^[\s]*?MVL\s*?SRCFILE=')([^']+)'\s*,\s*SERVER='([^']+)'\s*,.*?TARGETFILE='([^']+)'"`

Comment: Keith, thank you so much!  I am almost there with your help.  I still have a few edge cases that I need to work out. I will post the code, once I am done.